# NamedQuery gives an error

Tags: java, web-services, named-query

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to write NamedQuery haversine formula in NamedQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657256/how-to-write-namedquery-haversine-formula-in-namedquery)

I want to run below namedquery:

```
List<Object> result= em.createQuery("select sum(u.mlatitude) from UserGpsLocation u").getResultList();
return result.get(0);
```

Can anyone help me and tell me what's wrong with it?

Comment: This code is written as web service function and when I try to run it from browser it gives me 500 internal server error.

Comment: Infact my main aim is to run below Query: set @orig_lat=37.334542;

set @orig_lon=-121.890821;
set @dist=10;


select *, 3956*2*ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@orig_lat-abs(mlatitude))*pi()/180/2),2)
+COS(@orig_lat*pi()/180) * COS(abs(mlatitude)* pi()/180) *POWER(SIN((@orig_lon -mlogitude)* pi()/180/2),2))) 
as distance from user_gps_location  having distance < @dist ORDER BY distance    but I got an error in it.

Comment: Here is the link where I actual mention the whole problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657256/how-to-write-namedquery-haversine-formula-in-namedquery

Comment: why create another question when you already have one along the same lines?

Comment: Infact I was not getting solution of that so now I am trying from simple query which calculates sum so if I get the solution of this then may be I will go further for other parameters.